# Get the configuration of Apache's HttpClient

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x, apache-httpcomponents

Once I've created an Apache `HttpClient`, how do I get the configuration values from it (what used to be `HttpParams`)?

For example, if I do something like this to create a client:

```java
RequestConfig requestConfig = RequestConfig.custom()
    .setCircularRedirectsAllowed(true)
    .setAuthenticationEnabled(true)
    .setExpectContinueEnabled(true)
    .setConnectionRequestTimeout(10000);
    .build();
HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder
    .create()
    .setConnectionManager(new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager(createSchemeRegistry()))
    .setDefaultRequestConfig(requestConfig)
    .build();
```

How would I get the value of the connection request timeout from the `org.apache.http.client.HttpClient` instance? other configuration items?

For `AbstractHttpClient` there was a method `getParams` (or similar) but that's all gone away in favour of the `HttpClient` interface. There's an `InternalHttpClient` instance that's generated along the way but I think that's not exposed.

> The reason I'm interested in this is firstly for testing - I want to verify a HTTP Client was configured correctly, the other case is to present that information in a UI when debugging HTTP traffic - think of something like Charles proxy.

Comment: AFAIK you cannot use HttpClient. You need to store your RequestConfig object.

Comment: But just to understand if you *really* need to do this, why are you trying to pull out the configuration values?

Comment: you should be able to call getParams() method on HttpClient, how come it is gone?

Comment: @OnurA. it's deprecated. Not for removal, but it might be in the future. I'd avoid using deprecated features.

Comment: @LppEdd then you can use URIBuilder, I can post an example.

Comment: @OnurA. but he wants to pull out parameters from an already instantiated HttpClient object. You can't do that using an URIBuilder.

Comment: @LppEdd He can instantiate HttpClient using URIBuilder, hence he can pull out that info out of it.

Comment: @OnurA. he is already using RequestConfig for that.

Comment: @LppEdd I know, since OP has asked for getting parameters, I suggested using URIBuilder which offers to present params.

Comment: This is for a couple of reasons, the first is testing - I want to verify a HTTP Client was configured correctly, the other case is to present that information in a UI when debugging HTTP traffic - think of something like Charles proxy.

Comment: If you deal with a `InternalHttpClient` you can get the configuration through the `getConfig` method.